# Split directories in the MVC cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, directory-structure

I got a simple question and can't find the answer to it on the web.

Im using the framework CakePHP.

My question is:
Is it possible to split my model, controller and view directories.
Like this;

- Controller

  - CMS

    - [controller files of the cms]
  - Front-end

    - [controller files of the front-end]
- Model

  - CMS

    - [model files of the cms]
  - Front-end

    - [model files of the front-end]
- View

  - CMS

    - [view files of the cms]
  - Front-end

    - [view files of the front-end]

I really hope somebody can help me, because i have searched in the document 2.x Cakephp and search it all over the web and i cant find a solution for it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Oke, having 3 answers. Whats is the best method? Consider that the website is already in use, but the code behind it needs a cleaning up.. Which method is the best and easiest to use? Because im already almost an hour stuck to try the first answer.. Im sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as such, but you can have two different app directories (because you are essentially creating two different applications).

- CMS

  - Controller
  - Model
  - View
  - ...
- Frontend

  - Controller
  - Model
  - View
  - ...

You can [set up both apps to use the same webroot directory](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#sharing-cakephp-libraries-with-multiple-applications).

Comment: oke oke, now answering on your reaction without reading your link. I dont have to install cake twice? because i think you got the answer i was searching for.

Comment: The same link tells how the apps can share the same Cake installation. (Although I'm pretty sure they do that already by default.)

Comment: Oke thank you very much, im reading the link now. Maybe, i dont know. Im not used in making it so difficult. So i really hope this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides creating multiple app-s in the cake installation, you should consider Plugins as well:

```
app/Controller/...
app/Model/...
app/View/...

app/Plugins/CMS/Controller/...
app/Plugins/CMS/Model/...
app/Plugins/CMS/View/...

app/Plugins/Admin/Controller/...
app/Plugins/Admin/Model/...
app/Plugins/Admin/View/...

(...)
```

See the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

You could define with `App::build()` the additional directories in your `app/Config/bootstrap.php` file.